# How to Migrate a single Team project from TFS 2012 to Azure DevOps Services?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

Is there any way to migrate a single team project from TFS 2012 Update3 /15 to Existing Azure DevOps Services with the change set history and work items?

Please let me know if there is a process to get it done.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A single team project? No. An entire team project collection? Yes, if you upgrade to a modern version of TFS/Azure DevOps Server first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to migrate one single team project. However, you can try to:

1. Upgrade your current TFS to Azure DevOps Server ([Upgrade your deployment to the latest version of Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops)).
2. Use [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) to migrate work items. ([TFS 2017 Migration To VSTS with VSTS Sync Migrator](https://mohamedradwan.com/2017/09/15/tfs-2017-migration-to-vsts-with-vsts-sync-migrator/))
3. Import your TFVC repository into GIT ([Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-from-TFVC?view=azure-devops)) and move it into Azure Devops project ([Import a Git repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops)).